# How do you display POST data with cURL?

Tags: curl, debug

As an example, POSTing to a web server with the -v argument:

```
curl -v http://testserver.com/post -d "firstname=john&lastname=doe"
```

And the output

```
> POST /post HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8l zlib/1.2.3
> Host: testserver.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 28
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
(etc)
```

There is no mention of the data that I posted.

Is there an option in cURL to display the string "firstname=john&lastname=doe" in the output?

Note: Obviously the string I want is in the command I executed, but there are several other post options such as --form and --data-ascii etc. I'd like to see the raw data being sent to the server.

Comment: You can also run tcpdump to capture the actual data being sent to the server. Or wireshark (better) if you have that.

Comment: I'm not sure you can.  Is this an example of security by obscurity?  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198462/get-versus-post-in-terms-of-security

Answer (score 237, accepted):

The closest I got without using `tcpdump` is using the `--trace-ascii` option:

```
~ curl http://w3.org/ -d "hello=there" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
== Info: About to connect() to w3.org port 80 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 128.30.52.45... == Info: connected
== Info: Connected to w3.org (128.30.52.45) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 210 bytes (0xd2)
0000: POST / HTTP/1.1
0011: User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.1
0051: 9.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8l zlib/1.2.3
0070: Host: w3.org
007e: Accept: */*
008b: Content-Length: 11
009f: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
00d0: 
=> Send data, 11 bytes (0xb)
0000: hello=there
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work when you're posting `multipart/form-data`:

```
~ curl http://w3.org/ -F hello=there -F testing=123 --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
== Info: About to connect() to w3.org port 80 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 128.30.52.45... == Info: connected
== Info: Connected to w3.org (128.30.52.45) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 270 bytes (0x10e)
0000: POST / HTTP/1.1
0011: User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.1
0051: 9.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8l zlib/1.2.3
0070: Host: w3.org
007e: Accept: */*
008b: Content-Length: 244
00a0: Expect: 100-continue
00b6: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------
00f6: --------19319e4d1b79
010c: 
<= Recv header, 32 bytes (0x20)
0000: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

Comment: I know it is your own answer, but I think you can accept this as the correct answer. It solved it for me anyway, thanks :-)

Comment: @DarrenCook It's been a while--I didn't even realise this question wasn't answered!

Comment: Remove any `-v` or `--verbose` as they override the trace directive.

Comment: It doesn't work with https either as the data is encrypted ... :(

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger It works fine with https. I just tried it and saw the payload. The data is encrypted but since you are the endpoint of the connection, you have all the data available to you, and therefore curl can see it.

Comment: Using `--trace-ascii` worked for me on OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion. I have uploaded a multipart form entity with two images and a json body and everything worked as expected

Comment: The `--trace-ascii` works for me on Cygwin for multipart data as well!

Comment: Instead of `--trace-ascii /dev/stdout` you can `--trace-ascii -` (dash)

Comment: Any idea how to pass `--trace-ascii` to curl while accessing it from PHP code? I could not find any equivalent option @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 53):

Or you could test with https://httpbin.org/

```
$ curl https://httpbin.org/post -d "firstname=john&lastname=doe"
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "firstname": "john", 
    "lastname": "doe"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "27", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.43.0"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "*.*.*.*", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Comment: While this is not useful to see actual data sent like Gert's answer, it is useful that it parses the response so one can know whether there is format error.

Answer (score 30):

Would like to add netcat alternative

```
#!/bin/bash
nc -l 8080 &

curl "http://localhost:8080" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data @- <<EOF
{
  "me": "$USER",
  "something": $(date +%s)
}
EOF
```

Comment: I can't listen to port 8080 with `nc` because it is already in use(by the application). What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 27):

`--trace -` works with curl 7.58 and shows you the POST body:

```
$ curl --trace - -d 'foo=bar' http://example.org
== Info: Rebuilt URL to: http://example.org/
== Info:   Trying 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Connected to example.org (2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 144 bytes (0x90)
0000: 50 4f 53 54 20 2f 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d POST / HTTP/1.1.
0010: 0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 2e 6f .Host: example.o
0020: 72 67 0d 0a 55 73 65 72 2d 41 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 rg..User-Agent: 
0030: 63 75 72 6c 2f 37 2e 35 38 2e 30 0d 0a 41 63 63 curl/7.58.0..Acc
0040: 65 70 74 3a 20 2a 2f 2a 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e ept: */*..Conten
0050: 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 37 0d 0a 43 6f 6e t-Length: 7..Con
0060: 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20 61 70 70 6c 69 tent-Type: appli
0070: 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 2d 77 77 77 2d 66 6f 72 cation/x-www-for
0080: 6d 2d 75 72 6c 65 6e 63 6f 64 65 64 0d 0a 0d 0a m-urlencoded....
=> Send data, 7 bytes (0x7)
0000: 66 6f 6f 3d 62 61 72                            foo=bar
== Info: upload completely sent off: 7 out of 7 bytes
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
0010: 0a                                              .
<= Recv header, 22 bytes (0x16)
```

Comment: This is the best answer, because it also works for mulitpart/form-data requests, without having to use a third party proxy

Comment: For `multipart/form-data`, it only shows the file name. Can it show the file content?

Answer (score 10):

You could use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and `curl --proxy localhost:8888`. Simples!

Comment: no, it does not work with https. Accepted answer is fine and easier.

Comment: `https` was not a requirement in the question :p

Comment: @CasparHarmer what's your prob with the accepted answer?
if you need more, TCPdump does the deal.

Comment: This happened 3 years ago. I cannot remember.